# How do I write a win32 assembly program that outputs to the current console rather than creating a new one?

Tags: winapi, assembly, cmd

I'm using [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65224-intro-to-win32-assembly-using-nasm-part-3/) code, compiling with nasm and linking with alink. Whenever I run the resulting exe in bash it spawns a new console separate from the existing command shell.
How would I write a program that uses the original console it was executed within rather than spawning a new console?

Comment: Did you try if the same happens if you run the program from cmd.exe shell instead of your "bash"?

Comment: Excuse me, I'm screwing up bash scripts with cmd.exe. I thought cmd could also be called bash, just like how the linux command line could be called sh. I am using cmd.exe. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Did you link for subsystem "console"? If you did not this is what would happen, i.e. if you link for Win32 subsystem, there is no default console.

Comment: @user: There is no *Win32* subsystem.

Answer (score 3):

From the code:

```
;; Since this is a Windows subsystem program, we need to allocate a console,
;; in order to use one. 
call [AllocConsole]
```

In other words, it is quite explicitly creating a brand new console.  To make it use the existing console, link it as a Console subsystem application rather than a Windows subsystem application, and remove the call to AllocConsole().

Comment: The "-subsys con" argument for alink cleared it all up. Thank you!